# Can memset on boost::shared_array cause any problems?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a boost::shared_array buffer that is nulled occasionally using memset function. I suspect that this buffer is being corrupted from time to time and probably memset is the reason.

EDIT: to clarify things up here is the code:

```
boost::shared_array<char>   m_buf;  
m_buf( new char[(unsigned int)m_bufSize] )
memset( m_buf.get(), 0xCD, (size_t)m_bufSize );
```

Comment: You should probably post the relevant code fragment where you are zeroing the buffer.

Comment: Using correctly you won't have any problems with `memset` it's just a memory filler. Just make sure you're using it with raw buffer and the size is correct

Comment: Are you calling `memset` on the `shared_array` itself, or the array it owns? What is the element type in the array?

Comment: The code is not full and the 2nd line doesn't make sense. But that apart your approach looks correct to me so the problem is probably in some other part.

Comment: You should probably use Valgrind to find out the exact location of your memory corruption. From the code you've posted, it seems fine, so it's likely somewhere else.